# HTML blank spaces in email

Tags: html, vb6

A VB6 applications sends a HTML email.  Please have a look at the code below.  The email received has all the blank spaces stripped out i.e. all of the spaces on line 7 are stripped out and the email sent says: "this is a test".  Is there a way to send a HTML email with all of the spaces.

```
strMailText = strMailText & "<b><font size=""2"" face=""Arial""><br>Test Email</font></b><br><br>"
strMailText = strMailText & "<table border='1'>"
strMailText = strMailText & "<tr>"
strMailText = strMailText & "<td><b><font size=""2"" face=""Arial"">Test Column</font></b></td>"
strMailText = strMailText & "</tr>"

strMailText = strMailText & "<td><font size=""2"" face=""Arial"">This is a         test</font></td>"
strMailText = strMailText & "<tr>"
strMailText = strMailText & "table"

SendEMail strEmailServer, "test@test.com", strEMailTo, _
                                "Test Email", strMailText, True
```

Comment: Have you tried using `&nbsp;` instead of the spaces?

Comment: Note that if you view the source of the final email as received the spaces should still be present. If _not_ then you might have more than just an HTML issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most html rendering engines collapse multiple consecutive spaces. try writing instead of space, non-breaking spaces: `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`

Answer (score 7):

use `&nbsp;` instead of blank spaces.

`&nbsp` In computer-based text processing and digital typesetting, a non-breaking space, no-break space or non-breakable space (NBSP) is a variant of the space character that prevents an automatic line break (line wrap) at its position.

So this line

```
`strMailText = strMailText & "<td><font size=""2"" face=""Arial"">This is a         test</font></td>"`
```

should be written as:

```
strMailText = strMailText & "<td><font size=""2"" face=""Arial"">This is a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test</font></td>"
```

**Edited:**

**OR Another Method**

Use a `<span>` tag instead of spaces and give it padding or margins like this

```
<span style='padding-left: 15px;'></span>
```

So it should look like:

```
strMailText = strMailText & "<td><font size=""2"" face=""Arial"">This is<span style='padding-left: 15px;'></span>test</font></td>"
```

Comment: Using spaces for alignment in HTML is and alwasy has been horrible. How about using a proper alignment system?

Comment: @Deanna: Use a `<span>` tag instead of spaces and give it padding or margins like this : `<span style='padding-left: 15px;'></span>`

Answer (score 2):

**Our findings from using Litmus to test these methods**

While `&nbsp;` is supported by many email clients, some, such as Gmail (web) and iPhone Mail cause small anchor text underline spaces to be shown in some cases if an `<a href="">` happens to be nearby.

Trying the `<span style="padding-left: 15px;"></span>` method,  sadly, some email clients such as Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013, and Outlook 2019 simply show no space whatsoever.

But replacing these with something like `img src="pixels.gif" width="15" height="2" style="border: none; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;">` (a simple blank gif to force the space) is supported by absolutely every single email client in Litmus. (Note that we don't use a 1px x 1px sized gif, as we've heard that this could potentially lead to the email being marked as spam. Alternatively, we use a 2x2 gif.)

Comment: Any particular reason you went with a GIF (vs. JPG)?

Answer (score 0):

HTML strips out multiple spaces and replaces it by a single one. To solve your problem use `&nbsp;` instead of space.

`strMailText = strMailText & "<td><font size=""2"" face=""Arial"">This is a &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; test</font></td>"`